# What's the convention with types and separate XML schema files?

Tags: xsd

I'm developing a rather large XML Schema to integrate multiple disparate systems.  Each system has messages that consist of multiple fields.  I've written the schemas so that each field is represented as a type (either simple or complex), while the entire message is represented as an element with a sequence of multiple types.

**When defining types using XSD, what is the convention in terms of how you break up your files?**
I've been going down the path of having a separate XSD file for each type that I am defining, then a single XSD file that defines the message and imports the required XSD files.

[Here's a simplified example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHmiv.png) showing the structure (can't post images, no reputation).

Type schemas (fields) have a namespace ending in "types", while message schemas have a namespace ending in "messages".

My reasoning was that it would be easier to compose new types using existing types if they were defined in their own file, and that versioning types might be easier.

Is there a better approach?  I'm relatively new to XML and Schemas.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes no sense to have one schema per type. One schema per domain area, yes, but not one per type.

For instance, you might have one schema to define types related to customers, and another schema to define types related to products. You might have a separate schema to define common types like people and addresses, which might be used by the customer schema and also by the product schema (product sales rep, vendor address).

You might combine these in a schema related to order processing, since it involves orders made by customers for products.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the response.  So let's say I have around 500 types that will need to be defined, and another 80 messages or so.  There is some reuse of types in messages, but not a ton.  You're saying that I should have those 500 complex types defined in a single file, and the messages defined in another?  Keep in mind, my namespaces on the types are all the same, they are just in different files.

Comment: I should clarify that most of these messages are within the same domain.

Comment: If there is no rational basis for breaking them into multiple files, then yes, I'd keep them in a single file as opposed to using a non-rational basis to break them into one file per type.

Comment: While I wouldn't call it non-rational, as I'm coming from a Java and C/C++ background where most of the time you have separate class or struct files for each type, I appreciate the answer.  For instance, when I run JAXB against my schema, I still get a separate Java class for every type defined.

Comment: @Brian: that's fine, for Java, which will compile each class into an individual piece of metadata. XSD is not compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Are the separate xsd files you created completely unrelated to eachother? For example if one xsd file handles the sales domain and the other one handles the payments domain, you should give each schema a unique domain specific targetNamespace. This approach is called "Heterogeneous namespace design" and you are using it now. I believe it is best suited for your requirement. Since you are having multiple disparate systems it is better to maintain them in separate xsd files with different targetNamespaces. This enhances re-usability and reduces redundancy of types/fields. It also prevents namespace collisions. However if you have a large number of imports it becomes a challenge to manage and there will be dependency on the granularity of the types defined in the imported schemas.

If they are related to each other you should go for "Homogeneous namespace design".

There are two other approaches for XML Schema design:Homogenous Namespace Design and Chameleon Namespace Design which may not best suit your specific requirement. You can further get details on the benefits/drawbacks of all these three different schema design approaches at http://technologyandleadership.com/three-schema-design-approaches/